# Where to get Java packages for Google Pay services?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-api, google-pay

I need to implement Google Pay Passes loyalty card as described in [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/pay/passes/guides/implement-the-api/save-passes-to-google-pay?feed=native-android-app#use-native-android-sdk), but I am unable to implement it, because I am missing some `com.google.android.gms.pay` which are not imported as default in Android Studio.

Where to get those packages?

```
import com.google.android.gms.pay.Pay;
import com.google.android.gms.pay.PayApiAvailabilityStatus;
import com.google.android.gms.pay.PayClient;
```

I was not able to found them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to find it on Google Maven repo here: https://maven.google.com/web/index.html?q=com.google.android.gm#com.google.android.gms:play-services-pay:16.0.0

Comment: Great answer. Thank you!